# How to manage concurrency in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency

I'm stuck with this. To make it simpler, let's say I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_bags_oranges` (
  `idbag` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `n_oranges` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idbag`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

And I'm developing a php script that represents the situation in which users grab oranges. This is what I'm doing:

1. I use a `SELECT` to check if there are oranges in the given idgab (n_oranges > 0)
2. If so, I `UPDATE` the table subtracting 1 to n_oranges

But it may happen the following when there is just one orange in a bag:

1. User A wants to grab an orange. The ´SELECT´ says there is one orange.
2. User B wants to grab an orange. The ´SELECT´ says there is one orange.
3. User A grab the orange. I `UPDATE` the table and now n_oranges = 0.
4. User B is able to grab the orange because his `SELECT` said that there was one orange.

How can I solve this question? Transactions? `LOCK TABLES`? Since I can't check this situation there is no way to know if I'm doing well or wrong.

Comment: Do an [intention lock](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38079598). Yours will be somewhat similar, but with a decrement. Split second, safe.

Comment: Did you try add a check again n_oranges before you procceed to update in one step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [locking reads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html).
In detail:

- make sure [autocommit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html#glos_autocommit) is disabled
- `START TRANSACTION`
- `SELECT ... FROM tbl_bags_oranges WHERE ... FOR UPDATE`
- do whatever else you need to do in your code
- save the new value`UPDATE tbl_bags_oranges SET ...`
- `COMMIT`

In this case in your scenario the second query would block until the first transaction commits hence no race condition would occur

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can do a checking when you update the table something like this:

```
UPDATE `tbl_bags_oranges`
SET n_oranges=n_oranges-1 
WHERE n_oranges>=1;
```

You may modify the code based on your situation.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I wanted the question to be as simpler as possible to made it clear and I didn’t realize that my example was too much simple. Actually  I have to check values from 3 different tables and then update one of them.