# How to avoid inserting duplicates into MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have an analytics platform with lots of users and hundreds of inserting clicks / minute.

Sometimes I see that the exact same click is inserted to the Database within the same second and it becomes a duplicate of the other.

I have a system which checks if the table has the same value and not letting the other inserted if it finds one.

However in this case it looks to me that they're inserted into the DB in the exact same milisecond.

What can I do here?

Comment: don't check-then-insert. as you're finding, it's subject to race conditions. use a unique key. let the DB enforce the uniqueness

Comment: You have 2 options, have a duplicate Key in the databse and use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the other is INSERT IGNORE if its already in the databse it will ignore it

Comment: If you're recording clicks and when they happened, I would think you would want to know how many, including those that happened simultaneously. If that is the case, you may want to be inserting a click count and having the `ON DUPLICATE` clause increment that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My favorite: `insert ignore myTable (col1, col2, ...) ...`

where **unique** key(s) are setup beforehand to forbid the insert. It would appear that you do not care so much that it was previously inserted as much as you care that the end result is not dupes.

Note: the unique keys can be multi-column keys (composites)

A word of warning about `insert ignore`: it should not be implemented without careful thought of its ramifications for sensitive systems that need to know that the row was truly already there. It is ideal for "make sure it is there".

**Option B:** One could look into *intention locks*, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38079598), but crafted for your particular use-case. Steer toward INNODB row-level locking that is swifty, and certainly not table locks. Most things come with a trade-off. The downside of locking is diminished concurrency.

**Option C:** For the faint-of-heart (sometimes me). And this is what I would do if hired out and wish not to have peer backlash later. Perform an `Insert ... on Duplicate Key Update` (`IODKU`), and have a bogus column like `touches` that is an int that you increment for the Update part of the IODKU. Example below:

```
insert myTable (col1, col2, col3) values (p1,p2,p3) 
on duplicate key update touches=touches+1;
```

That above would be in a most minimalist form. A view below is what I use in `C#` where I care about more columns in the "update part of IODKU", but just to show that, if it benefits anyone:

[image]

A final thought on IODKU: it is mandatory to have a unique key (primary or just unique) that causes the "clash" to occur. Thus, the statement knows whether or not to perform the insert or the update. Without such a unique key clash, a new row will be inserted.

Back to the op issue, the reason your system probably already had the row there was due to high concurrency use without locking.

Answer (score 0):

If the system's architecture allows it I would create two-tier solution. First, a temporary table where duplicate data would be inserted. The temporary table's name can contain a sharding parameter, for example, an hour number. The system will periodically export data from temporary tables into the main storage table, discarding duplicate data. Then it can discard the temporary tables.